# How can I donwload a file in NetSuite with SOAP and NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, soap, netsuite, endpoint

I want to donwload a file in NetSuite with SOAP and NodeJS but I am not sure how to do it, I don't know if I can use the endpoint with the user and password verification or I have to use the tokens or if I am using the correct endpoint for that or is something else that I don't know.

I have this code that is supposed to donwload a file from Netsuite, but does'nt work, I did'nt found a lot of information about it or I did'nt understant it.

```
const soapEnvelopeDonwload = `
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:typens="urn:types.filecabinet_2021_1.documents.webservices.netsuite.com" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <typens:get>
            <typens:baseRef xsi:type="typens:RecordRef">
                <typens:internalId>${fileId}</typens:internalId>
            </typens:baseRef>
        </typens:get>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
`;//download


const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
    SOAPAction: 'get',
    Authorization: `NLAuth nlauth_account=${accountID}, 
nlauth_email=${username}, nlauth_signature=${password}`,
};

axios
    .post(`https://${accId}.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/NetSuitePort_2021_1`,
 soapEnvelopeDonwload, { headers })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error.response.data); 
    });
```

This is the error that the console gives me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>
<faultstring>org.xml.sax.SAXException: Invalid type: 
{urn:types.filecabinet_2021_1.documents.webservices.netsuite.com}RecordRef</faultstring><detail>
<ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">partners035</ns1:hostname></detail>
</soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thanks a lot.